# Restangular: Error: Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I want to inject Restangular in my app to communicate with via REST.

So, here I am know with an error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: RestangularProvider <- Restangular <- Api
```

`Api` is my own module here. What I'm doing:

> 1. Creating a main module called Dashboard
> 2. Creating a submodule called API

Now I want to use Restangular, but couldn't figure out how Angular is managing the dependencies...

Here is my sub-module where I inject Restangular:

```
angular.module( 'dashboard.api', ['restangular']).factory('Api', ['$http', 'Config', 'Restangular', function($http, Config, Restangular) {
```

My main module, Dashboard, doesn't need to inject Restangular, right?

```
angular.module( 'dashboard', [ 'dashboard.api'])
```

> How is the injection-depency working within submodules? How can I
>   integrate Restangular in my app?

EDIT: Source file is included:
[image]

Comment: did u add the angular-resource.js file ?

Comment: what is the `restangular` module u used ?

Comment: This could also happen due to re-declaration of `dashboard` or `dashboard.api` module. Make sure you have call module declaration api (that takes 2 parameters) only once for each module.

Comment: @Chandermani can you explain this further please? I have app.module('dashboard'), once, and then the module dashboard.api, also just once. I have other submodules (dashboard.utils) though. But this shouldn't affect the dashboard module, should it?

Comment: @K.Toress v1.4.0 - 2015-04-03

Comment: Look at this post http://blog.technovert.com/2014/10/dependency-injection-fails-angularjs/ section `Duplicate module declaration`.

Comment: R u missing single quotes in this angular.module( 'dashboard', [ dashboard.api'])

Comment: I think the correct way for handling this problem is configuring restangular in run method of angularjs

Comment: But I want to call Restangular inside my API module. That's the purpose of a module, right? If it would be in run, I cannot access is elsewhere, just with rootScope @Reena

Comment: isnt u need to inject `$resource` instead of  `Restangular` ?

Comment: @K.Toress Don't think so: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#quick-configuration-for-lazy-readers

Comment: Please have a look at this. This explains that how second module overwrites the restangular dependency.. http://www.ngroutes.com/questions/AUuAFYfha5vEqxqlLEkG/restangular-error-unknown-provider-restangularprovider-restangular.html

Comment: @Reena I got this... but see... I'm injecting it in the SECOND module, so it should be at least there, right? I've tried it either way.

Comment: Where r u using RestangularProvider in the code?

Comment: So, main-module: dashboard; Second-Module: dashboard.api; I'm using it in Dashboard.api; thanks a lot so far

Comment: angular.module( 'dashboard.api', ['restangular']).factory('Api', ['$http', 'Config', 'Restangular', function($http, Config, RestangularProvider)

Comment: So the problem is, as soon as I load restangular, my app fails. So it doesn't find this module at all. Which is strange because the build process takes it and moves  the file to the dist folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I found the problem and the solution.

You have to differ between `restangular`(the module) and `Restangular` the service.

First, you have to include the main module of restangular into your app:

For me, it was this (`polygon` is a submodule of my app:

`angular.module('polygons', ['restangular']);`

Then, I wanted to inject restangular into a factory of that submodule:

```
angular.module('polygons').factory('polygonService', ['Restangular', polygonService]);

function polygonService(Restangular) {
// ...
});
```

This works for me. Hope this helps.